# TextView and strings use (how to)

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I am using two TextViews, is it possible so that I can make TextViewOne display "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star" as a result of the input "1" in TextViewOne in the same activity.

```
String check = display.getText().toString(); 
if (check.contentEquals("1")) { 
    tvtitle.setText("Twinkle Twinkle Little Star");
} else { 
    tvtitle.setText(""); 
}
```

**EDIT**
I created a custom keypad, and when I use the above, it doesnt work, when 1 is inputed, nothing shows in the second TextView box, want to try Satyen's suggestion now.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you need to bind this function to an event i believe

Comment: Well, does it work? Are you actually experiencing a problem?

Comment: #1 rule for asking a question in SO: Ask a question.

Comment: @GrahamBorland It doesnt work. I'm actually just learning.. so forgive my mistakes.

Comment: This is quite basic Android behaviour. I suggest you try to do some tutorials to get a better knowledge of the system. Try http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html or this Youtube series http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RHtKIo_KDI&list=PLE08A97D36D5A255F

Comment: @Einar thank you, though I'm current using the The New Boston 200 Videos. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can easily do that just implement `onTextChangeListener()` in your `Activty`.

then `display.setOnTextChangeListener(this);`

then in its `textChanged()` method put your `if()` condition

Comment: So why don't you mark this as an answer?